# Python: how to replace a substring with a number of its occurences?

Tags: python, string, replace, count, run-length-encoding

Let's say I have a string presented in the following fashion:

```py
st = 'abbbccccaaaAAbccc'
```

The task is to encode it so that single characters are followed by a number of their occurences:

```py
st = 'a1b3c4a3A2b1c3'
```

I know one possible solution but it's too bulky and primitive.

```py
s = str(input())
l = len(s)-1
c = 1
t = ''
if len(s)==1:
    t = t +s+str(c)
else:
    for i in range(0,l):
        if s[i]==s[i+1]:
            c +=1
        elif s[i]!=s[i+1]:
            t = t + s[i]+str(c)
            c = 1
        for j in range(l,l+1):
            if s[-1]==s[-2]:
            t = t +s[j]+str(c)
        elif s[-1]!=s[-2]:
            t = t +s[j]+str(c)
            c = 1
print(t)
```

Is there any way to solve this shortly and elegantly?

P.S: I'm an unexperienced Python user and a new StackOverflow member, so I beg my pardon if the question is asked incorrectly.

Comment: Show us the way you know, so we have an idea of what you consider "bulky and primitive".

Comment: I suggest you search for run length encoding.

Comment: Put the code in the question.  It's hard to read lengthy code in a comment.

Comment: @khelwood That's quite helpful, thanks!

Comment: @JohnGordon The code is in the question now, but I must warn you - it's really bulky! I suppose dictionary or list should be used instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take advantage of the standard library:

```
from itertools import groupby

st = "abbbccccaaaAAbccc"

print("".join("{}{}".format(key, len(list(group))) for key, group in groupby(st)))
```

Output:

```
a1b3c4a3A2b1c3
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

just loop through and count.  There are more graceful snippets but this will get the job done and is clear:

```
count = 1
char = st[0]
new_st = []
for c in st[1:]:
    if c == char:
        count += 1
    else:
      new_st.append(char + str(count))
      char = c
      count = 1
new_st.append(char + str(count))
s2= "".join(new_st)

print(s2)  # 'a1b3c4a3A2b1c3'
```

If you want a fancy recursive solution:

```
def compose(s):
    if not s:
        return ""

    count = 1
    for char in s[1:]:
        if s[0] != char:
            break
        count += 1
    return s[0] + str(count) + compose(s[count:])
```